# Variable won't display change

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an interactive book and I want the page number to be shown, but the page number stays 0.

I change the contents via function. I tried to change the variable by calling the function on button click, but the page number (the 'page' variable) doesn't display the change.

What's going wrong?

```js
var page = 0;
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = "Current page: " + page + " | Enter page number: ";

function f1() {
  document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = "<p>You are a pet hamster. You are waiting for your owner to come home. What do you want to do in the meantime?</p></br><button type='button' onclick='f2()'>Run in the wheel</button> <button type='button' onclick='f3()'>Eat</button>";
  page = 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Hamster Adventure</h1>
  <button type='button' onclick='f1()'>Start</button>
</div>
</br>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: There is no binding between html and some variable, so every time the variable changes you then have to update the html as well. It will not auto update itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `page` variable, you'll need to update the contents of the `#page` element to reflect the new value. You can set its `innerHTML` each time the page changes.

```js
var page;
var pagination = document.getElementById('page');

function setPageNum(page) {
  pagination.innerHTML = "Current page: " + page + " | Enter page number: ";
}

function f1() {
  document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = "<p>You are a pet hamster. You are waiting for your owner to come home. What do you want to do in the meantime?</p></br><button type='button'>Run in the wheel</button> <button type='button' onclick='f3()'>Eat</button>";
  setPageNum(2);
}

setPageNum(1);
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Hamster Adventure</h1>
  <button type='button' onclick='f1()'>Start</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="page"></div>
```

---

Incidentally, you might consider a more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) method of stepping through pages.

```js
var pagination = document.getElementById('page');
var contents = document.getElementById('contents');

var pages = {
  1: "<p>You are a pet hamster. You are waiting for your owner to come home. What do you want to do in the meantime?</p></br><button type='button' onclick='setPage(2)'>Run in the wheel</button> <button type='button'onclick='setPage(2)'>Eat</button>",
  2: "<p>This is step 2.</p></br><button type='button'onclick='setPage(3)'>Something</button> <button type='button' onclick='setPage(3)'>Something Else</button>",
  3: "<p>This is step 3.</p></br><button type='button'onclick='setPage(1)'>This One</button> <button type='button' onclick='setPage(1)'>Another One</button>"
};

function setPage(page) {
  contents.innerHTML = pages[page];
  pagination.innerHTML = "Current page: " + page;
}

setPage(1);
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Hamster Adventure</h1>
  <button type='button' onclick='f1()'>Start</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: And perhaps consider delegation and just change the textContent of the buttons and have fixed buttons shown or hidden. That in combination with external event handling

Comment: @mplungjan Agreed!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var page = 0;
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = "Current page: " + page + " | Enter page number: ";

function f1(val) {
val += 1;

document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = "<p>You are a pet hamster. You are waiting for your owner to come home. What do you want to do in the meantime?</p></br><button type='button' onclick='f2()'>Run in the wheel</button> <button type='button' onclick='f3()'>Eat</button>";
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = "Current page: " + val + " | Enter page number: ";

}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
<h1>Hamster Adventure</h1>
<button type='button' onclick='f1(0)'>Start</button>
</div>
</br>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers told you what was wrong with your code.

Have a study of this.

It should have enough bits of script to help you with your book

```js
const pages = [{
"text":"", "choices": [{"page":1,"text":"Start"}]},
  {
  "text": "You are a pet hamster. You are waiting for your owner to come home. What do you want to do in the meantime?",
  "choices" : [{
    "page": 2,
    "text": "Run in the wheel"
  }, {
    "page": 3,
    "text": "Eat"
  }]
},
{
  "text": "You are running in the wheel; what now?",
  "choices" : [{
    "page": 4,
    "text": "Stop and rest"
  }, {
    "page": 5,
    "text": "Run faster"
  }]
}];
let pageNumber = 0;
const pageSpan = document.getElementById("pageSpan");
const textDiv = document.getElementById("textDiv");
const choiceButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".choice")
const changePage = () =>  {
  const page = pages[pageNumber]; console.log(page)
  textDiv.innerHTML = page ? page.text : "You are eaten by a Grue";
  const choices = page ? page.choices : [];
  pageSpan.textContent = pageNumber;
  choiceButtons.forEach((but,i) => {
    but.classList.toggle("hide",!choices[i])
    but.innerText = choices[i] ? choices[i].text : "";
  }); 
};
document.getElementById("gotoPage").max = pages.length;
document.getElementById("contents").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const page = pages[pageNumber];
  if (page) {
    pageNumber = page.choices[tgt.id==="choice1" ? 0 : 1].page
    changePage();
  }  
})
changePage()
document.getElementById("gotoPage").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  pageNumber = +this.value;
  changePage()
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#gotoPage {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <h1>Hamster Adventure</h1>
  <div id="textDiv"></div>
  <button type='button' class="choice hide" id="choice1"></button>
  <button type='button' class="choice" id="choice2">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="page">Current page: <span id="pageSpan"></span> | Enter page number:<input type="number" min="0" id="gotoPage" /></div>
```